# ¿Como puedo resolver el error (25,13) de android studio 3.0?

Tags: android-studio, mongodb

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Show in Filw
Show in Project Structure Dialog
```

Esto es lo que aparece cuando trato de compilar la App.

Estoy intentando usar MongoDB Stitch y coloque en build.Grandle (Project prueba)  los siguiente:

```
maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
```

viendose asi:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

tambien en build.grandle(Module app) coloco el codigo:

```
compile 'org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

en las dependencias viendose asi:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hasslerisaac.ruffy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.mongodb:stitch:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

todo esto como lo muestra la pagina de MongoDB para unir la aplicación Stitch del Cluster a la aplicación. Por favor ayuda.